# extends TabActivity not working in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabactivity

I am trying to create a tabbed application however, I'm finding problems when trying to run the application and the main class extends TabActivity.
The Main Class code is the following:

```
package org.practical.newsupdate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class NewsPage extends TabActivity{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newspage);

    TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    host.setup();

    new Intent().setClass(this, LocalNews.class);
    TabSpec localTab = host.newTabSpec("Local");
    localTab.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.local),
    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on));
    localTab.setContent(R.id.local_tab);
    host.addTab(localTab);

    new Intent().setClass(this, ForeignNews.class);
    TabSpec foreignTab = host.newTabSpec("Foreign");
    foreignTab.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.foreign),
    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on));
    foreignTab.setContent(R.id.foreign_tab);
    host.addTab(foreignTab);

    host.setCurrentTabByTag("Local");
}   
}
```

The XML is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/newsimages" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/newsimages" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newspage_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/menu_newspage" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/local_tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/foreign_tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

The log cat shows the following errors:

12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.practical.newsupdate/org.practical.newsupdate.NewsPage}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:131)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:254)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at org.practical.newsupdate.NewsPage.onCreate(NewsPage.java:13)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-25 18:11:24.846: E/AndroidRuntime(569):  ... 11 more

The error that is showing is that the application has suddenly stopped working. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please post the exception you are getting in the logcat

Comment: i posted the logcat exceptions in the question just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is giving the error
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

Is the package name same as Java package name or different. If yes please import full qualified R class